# Why is my Java static block is not executing? (Extremely simple example. Other answers don't seem to apply.)

Tags: java, static, classloader

I've included my code below. Following some other examples, I even tried to dynamically load the class in order to force it to run the static block, but that doesn't solve my problem. The class is loaded and class.getName() is printed successfully, but still, when it gets to the last line in the main method it throws an error saying the array is null.

All the other answers address things which don't seem to apply here, like how using the "final" keyword can allow the compiler to skip static blocks. Any help is appreciated!

```
package helper;

public class StaticTest {
    
    public static boolean [] ALL_TRUE;
    
    private static void setArray(){
        ALL_TRUE = new boolean[8];
        for(int i=0;i<ALL_TRUE.length;i++){
            ALL_TRUE[i] = true;
        }
    }
    
    static {
        setArray();
    }
    
    public static void main(String [] args){
        ClassLoader cLoader = StaticTest.class.getClassLoader();
        try{
            Class aClass = cLoader.loadClass("helper.StaticTest");
            System.out.println("aClass.getName() = " + aClass.getName());
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
        System.out.println(StaticTest.ALL_TRUE[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: When I run your code it prints "aClass.getName() = helper.StaticTest" and "true" because your array has been successfully initialised. What do you get and what did you expect?

Comment: Can confirm: @PSkunker, did you actually run this code? There is nothing in it that would cause the static block not to run, and indeed if I run this, it works fine (prints 'true'). tested on many JDKs, too, just to be sure.

Comment: I got

aClass.getName() = helper.StaticTest
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot load from byte/boolean array because "helper.StaticTest.ALL_TRUE" is null
 at helper.StaticTest.main(StaticTest.java:28)
C:\Users\pskunk\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\12.4\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\pskunk\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\12.4\executor-snippets\run.xml:94: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: Also, thanks for the quick responses. I'm using Apache Netbeans - could it be a netbeans-specific issue?

Comment: Maybe you should clean and recompile your code, to make sure the version you're running is actually the code you think it is.

Comment: Fresh clean and build. Tried both the "Run File" and the "Run Project" options. Both throw the same error.

Comment: @PSkunker It's rather unlikely netbeans is using a broken compiler internally. Something else is going on, but nothing in the question or the comment stream is giving the slightest idea as to what it might be, I'm afraid.

Comment: Note that the try block is a red herring. Just a one-liner main with `print(StaticTest.ALL_TRUE[0])` will print `true`, or crash with the exact error you pasted in comment 3 if the static block somehow didn't run.

Comment: UPDATE: It does seem to be an issue with Netbeans. When I run the code from the command line it works fine. Thanks for all the comments, and sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else lands here, the problem was that I had checked the Netbeans option "Compile on Save" (under Build->Compiling). Somehow, compiling files immediately upon saving was preventing the static block from being run.

Again, thanks to everyone who chimed in to verify that the code itself worked as expected.